# Can we make email as unique key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can we make email as the unique key in a database, so that the same user cannot register again and again?

here is my code

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ymi text NOT NULL,
country text NOT NULL,
Matrix text NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
email text NOT NULL,
number text NOT NULL,
 Dob text NOT NULL,
 fileToUpload text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (`id`)
)
```

Comment: You already got your answer, but be aware, that there are aliases. Example: `@gmail.com` and `@googlemail.com` can both be used for one address.

Comment: I'm using a WordPress here is code linkenthusionz.com/praaa/fulll

Comment: What are you exactly asking for? Of course you can - what keeps you from doing it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can create the email as unique key. And auto increment ID must be primary key..

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id int primary key autoincrement,
    name varchar(255) NULL,
    email varchar(190) UNIQUE)
```

And other columns can be added in same fashion.

Comment: This answer is correct but it should  point out that `email` needs to change type in order to be declared `unique` (the answer does this implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an email as a unique key

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
...
   UNIQUE KEY(index_column_,index_column_2,...) 
);


$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ymi text NOT NULL,
    country text NOT NULL,
    Matrix text NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    email varchar(190) NOT NULL,
    number text NOT NULL,
    Dob text NOT NULL,
    fileToUpload text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY unique_email (email)
)
```

Comment: just replace my answer query and try, coz It's working on my local

Comment: This should not be updated.  `text` is not appropriate for the `email` column type.